Can someone help me to identify this classical piece?
I'm trying to find the classical piece played by two young Japanese women under an instructor named Robert La Marchina. It an old record from 60s. The music starts at 7:17 :



It sounds like Bach to me, but impossible to know for me. Would be glad if anyone can spot it.

Welcome! Sorry, but identifying pieces of music are outside the remit of this site, so the question may soon be closed.
